# Which $k$ is the biggest number such that $2^x>kx$ for all $x\in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: analysis

For $k\in \mathbb{R}$, which $k$ is the biggest number such that $2^x>kx$ for all $x\in \mathbb{N}$? And which $k $ is the biggest number such that $2^x>kx$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$? And for $k\in \mathbb{Q}$? If you could tell me the general method to solve this kind of problems, that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x=0$ the inequality holds.
Dividing both sides by $x$,
$$\frac{2^x}{x}>k$$
For $x<0$, we can see that $\frac{2^x}{x}$ approaches $0$ as $x$ increases, and can get arbitrarily small when $x$ approaches $0$.

Therefore, for $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}$, no such $k$ exists. However, for $x\in \mathbb{R}^+$, we can find
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{2^x}{x}\right)=\frac{\ln\left(2\right)\cdot 2^xx-2^x}{x^2}$$
using the quotient rule, and find where the derivative is $0$ ($\frac{1}{\ln 2}$). This gives us the minimum of the function (check using a graph or other methods).
So we know
$$\frac{2^x}{x}\ge \ln(2)2^{\frac{1}{\ln(2)}}$$
so $k=\ln(2)2^{\frac{1}{\ln(2)}}-\varepsilon$ (where $\varepsilon$ is very very small so that the strictly greater than holds).
You can find a solution in a similar way for $x\in\mathbb{N}$ simply by checking small values of $x$ (in that case you get $k=2-\varepsilon$). The case where $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ is also doable since $x$ cannot approach $0$.

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry i can't cast a vote for that needs at least 15 reputation and my account is new, but i have accepted the answer.